# Cannot visualize "ts" with autoplot - Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to ts. I transform my column into `ts`, but cannot visualize with `autoplot`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfortify)
library(forecast)

test <- ts(raw_mongolia_monthly$Time_Period, start = 2014, frequency = 12)

         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     
Oct     Nov     Dec
2014 2014/01 2014/02 2014/03 2014/04 2014/05 2014/06 2014/07 2014/08 2014/09 
2014/10 2014/11 2014/12
2015 2015/01 2015/02 2015/03 2015/04 2015/05 2015/06 2015/07 2015/08 2015/09 
2015/10 2015/11 2015/12
2016 2016/01 2016/02 2016/03 2016/04 2016/05 2016/06 2016/07 2016/08 2016/09 
2016/10 2016/11 2016/12
2017 2017/01 2017/02 2017/03 2017/04 2017/05 2017/06   

class(test)
[1] "ts"

 autoplot(test) 

**Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale**
```

My data

```
> dput(test)
structure(c("2014/01", "2014/02", "2014/03", "2014/04", "2014/05", 
"2014/06", "2014/07", "2014/08", "2014/09", "2014/10", "2014/11", 
"2014/12", "2015/01", "2015/02", "2015/03", "2015/04", "2015/05", 
"2015/06", "2015/07", "2015/08", "2015/09", "2015/10", "2015/11", 
"2015/12", "2016/01", "2016/02", "2016/03", "2016/04", "2016/05", 
"2016/06", "2016/07", "2016/08", "2016/09", "2016/10", "2016/11", 
"2016/12", "2017/01", "2017/02", "2017/03", "2017/04", "2017/05", 
"2017/06"), .Tsp = c(2014, 2017.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

Checked multiple links, but still does not work. Do not see a solution which works for me.

The only thing I managed to do with this data without transforming into `ts` - visualize with ggplot `geom_point`, using

```
ggplot(raw_mongolia_monthly, aes(Time_Period, Value)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now used basic ggplot

```
ggplot(raw_mongolia_monthly, aes(Time_Period, Value, group = 1)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Finally got how to do it with `ts()` Kudos to [Forecasting Using R DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/forecasting-using-r) class

The code

```
myts <- ts(raw_mongolia_monthly[, 8], start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12)

autoplot(myts)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plot shown in the question does not correspond to the test data shown. 
 The test data is a ts series of character data whereas the plot shows numeric data plotted.

I suspect that there are errors in the question but taking it at face value it is asking to plot some years/months against themselves so convert the data to a `yearmon` object and then create a zoo object from that.  Now`autoplot` will work.

```
library(zoo)

ym <- as.yearmon(coredata(test), "%Y/%m")
z <- zoo(ym, ym)
autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearmon() + scale_y_yearmon()
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but how do you put "Value" on y-axis? It is not exactly what I want. I need months on x-axis and values on y.

Comment: There is no Value in your test data.  Please fix the question.